# Disable Visual Studio bookmark

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bookmarks

Bookmark has been one of my most use feature in VS. I used it as a fast navigation which eliminates the need to scroll everywhere. The naming features of the bookmarks are also very useful as I can put meaningful names instead of just the default numbering.

[image]

However I found that even when the bookmarks are disabled (as shown in the screenshot above), I will still ended up navigating to those bookmark when I am using the next bookmark shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>. I don't delete those bookmarks cause I might use them again later or just as a reference. Is there anyway to disable the bookmark in the way I stated above?

**Edit**: I am using VS2010 SP1

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I tried it on VS2010 SP1 and it works as expected for me.

Comment: @Doktorn Same as yours VS2010 SP1. After you disable the bookmarks and you double click on the bookmark will it navigate to it? Mine will still navigate to the bookmark even it is disabled, I prefer it to not navigate as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 14):

Ctrl+K,K toggles bookmarks in vs2010

Comment: I am aware of that keyboard shortcut, I wanted the disabled (not removed) bookmarks to not being navigate to when pressing the 'Next Bookmark'.

Comment: It should be CTRL + K, CTRL + K.